# Keep or Transfer Coins after mining reward?

Tags: wallet, mining-pools, mining-reward, zcash

I've been mining ZEC (pool) for the past month and noticed that most of the other people in the pool never had any balance on their wallets if I viewed them on the [zcash blockexplorer](https://zcash.blockexplorer.com/).

Is there a reason why people immediately transfer their coins to a different wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a reason why people immediately transfer their coins to a
>   different wallet?

If someone will hacking that mining pool, his able to steal all users coins. Move money to the cold-storage is a good practice. They're also can just move money to the exchange.

Comment: okay, do you know how exactly somebody would be able to access my wallet by hacking the pool?

Comment: It's depends on how pool have programmed, any program can be hacked. Here is an example https://bitcoinexchangeguide.com/nicehash-hacked-cryptocurrency-mining-pool/, they're might or not, nobody knows.